# Is there a way to stop a timer in Netlogo?

Tags: timer, netlogo

If you make a timer in Netlogo, is there a way to stop it?

Comment: what kind of timer? can you show the code you used to "make a timer"?

Comment: I'm referring to NetLogo's built-in "timer" function. I know it can be reset using "reset-timer", but I want to know whether it can be paused. I don't think it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in timer cannot be paused.

I think you will need to call `reset-timer`, but before calling it, add the current value of `timer` to a running total that you keep in a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the timer but I'm not sure if you can stop it.

More info on resetting it here:
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-timer

I think the timer will end with your end statement and there would be no way to stop in while its running where your creating it.

I dunno if that helps im kinda new to Netlogo....

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could specify the number of ticks you want to stop in a variable that you set (i.e. ticks-start ticks-end), and then use the stop and ticks commands to control it using code like the following:

```
globals [ ticks-start ticks-end ] ;Otherwise, setting slider/box in the interface instead
if (ticks > ticks-start) 
if (ticks >= ticks-end) [ stop ]
```